# Passing multiple parameters to with method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

Below is my `model` method which accepts an id and `auth` token.

```
Project.find( id: '22', authorization: auth)
```

Below is my test.

```
require 'project'

RSpec.describe Project do
  it 'finds an project' do
    project = class_double("project")    
    expect(project).to receive(:find).with() 
                             // How can i send id and authorization inside with       
  end
end
```

How can i make `this test pass` by passing `id` and `authorization` inside the `with`?.

Comment: What errors are you seeing when you pass both id and auth into with?  You should be able to use: `expect(project).to receive(:find).with(id, auth)` in your code if you define `id` and `auth` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`Project.find(id: '22', authorization: auth)` is shorthand for:
`Project.find({id: '22', authorization: auth})`

This means you're passing one parameter to 'find': a hash.

`expect(project).to receive(:find).with({id: the_id, authorization: the_auth})`

You can omit the curly braces if you wish.